# NoClassDefFoundError when running app on Samsung device but not when running on an emulator

Tags: java, android, jar, noclassdeffounderror

When I test my app on an emulator, (Nexus One API 21) it runs smoothly without fail. However, when I test the app on my own personal phone(Samsung Galaxy S5,Android version 5.0,also API 21), it crashed with a NoClassDefFoundError. This error occurs at a part of the code where I am using an external library from a jar file.(jaudiotagger) Could it be that my own android phone does not have the jdk to support the library? How do I resolve that?

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild project. Post logcat error.

Answer (score 0):

- First go to "Properties" of the project.
- then select "Java Build Path"
- after that select "Order and Export" Tab
- You should see the selected project's "src" and "gen" paths and
  dependencies here.
- The order how they listed were first "src" and then "gen" path
- Switch them, so that "gen" folder is build before the "src"

try it but I am not sure whether it will help you :/ In my case worked

Comment: Hi I'm sorry if this is a noob question but how do I go to the properties of the project?When I right click it,there is no properties shown. I'm using android studio 2.0

Comment: aa I was using Eclipse, but will try to find how to fix it in Android Studio

Comment: I think that its not adding the jar to the apk, so if u wont have libs folder in the project create one and try to put the jar file there

Comment: I've tried shifting the jar file into the libs folder but to no avail....funny thing is it works on emulator but not on my real phone